# C++ Why Is There "Unknown Type" When Class Header is Included?

Tags: c++

I have this header file and I'm trying to make variables of type `Item`. I've included `#include "Item.h"` and yet I still get a `unknown type name Item` error on both private variables when I compile.

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <vector>

#include "Item.h"

using std::vector;

class Player
{ 

public:

    // constructor
    Player( void );

    // destructor
    virtual ~Player( void );

private:

    Item item;
    std::vector <Item> inventory;

};

#endif  /* PLAYER_H */
```

Whats up with this?

Heres the `Item.h` that I'm including

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
#include "GlobalDefs.h"

class Item {
public:
    Item();
    Item(gold_t v, std::string n);

    virtual ~Item();

    // Getter
    inline virtual gold_t GetValue (void) 
    { 
        return value; 
    }

    // Getter
    inline virtual std::string GetName (void);

     // Getter
     virtual std::string GetItemText(void);

protected:
    gold_t value;
    std::string name;

};

#endif  /* ITEM_H */
```

Comment: Note: methods defined inside the class body are automatically inline so the `inline` keyword on `GetValue` is redundant. Also marking 0-parameter parameter lists as `void` is redundant too.

Comment: In the top of your code you have written "using std::vector". Isn't it unnecessary to declare a vector with "std::"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you include `Item.h` from your `cpp` file, `Player.h` is included from it. Then, `Player.h` includes `Item.h` again, but thanks to the include guard, this does virtually nothing.

Then, in the included `Player.h`, no `Item` is declared yet. Therefore, the compiler will emit the error.

Since nothing from `Player.h` is used in `Item.h`, remove `#include "Player.h"` from `Item.h`.

Comment: What if  `Item.h` did need to `#include "Player.h"`?

Comment: Modify the design to eliminate circular dependency.

Comment: I meant to ask how one would do that. If `Item` needs to accept a `Player` type as a parameter, how could you do that without reintroducing the circular dependency?

Comment: Use declaration `class Player;` and use reference as the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You're including `"Player.h"` in `"Item.h"` and make it [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). Since it's not necessary at all so just remove it.